# itoa for negative numbers?

Tags: assembly, mips

Bounty: +50 reputation points for anyone that provides the code to make this subroutine work with negative numbers.

I wrote a MIPS program to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius.  It opens its own output window (i.e. UART) and properly displays the value in Celsius.  It does all of this while making calls from C to assembly and vice versa.  Entire code posted below.

I am struggling with getting it to work with negative numbers.  Just drawing a blank right now for some reason.  How do I change my `itoa` function to write this check?

Anyone have any ideas how to get this working with negative values in MIPS?

```
.ent itoa
itoa:
  // putting the stack frame together
  addiu sp, sp, -16
  sw    fp, 12(sp)
  move  fp, sp
  sw    a0, 16(fp)
  sw    a1, 20(fp)
  sw    s0, 4(fp)
  sw    s1, 0(sp)

  // there is no divide immediate, so using s1
  li    s1, 10

  itoa_div_begin:
        divu  a0, s1
        mfhi  s0
        mflo  a0

        addiu s0, s0, 0x30
        addiu sp, sp, -1
        sb    s0, 0(sp)

        beq   a0, zero, itoa_div_done
        nop

        j     itoa_div_begin
        nop

  itoa_div_done:
  itoa_copy_begin:
        lb    s0, 0(sp)
        sb    s0, 0(a1)

        addiu sp, sp, 1
        subu  s1, sp, fp
        addiu a1, a1, 1

        beq   s1, zero, itoa_copy_done
        nop

        j     itoa_copy_begin
        nop

  itoa_copy_done:
  li    s0, 0
  sb    s0, 0(a1)

  move  v0, a1

  lw    a0, 16(fp)
  lw    a1, 20(fp)
  lw    s0, 4(fp)
  lw    s1, 0(fp)
  // stack frame
  move  sp, fp
  lw    fp, 12(sp)
  addiu sp, sp, 16

  jr    ra
  nop

.end itoa
```

Comment: cant give you code, but you have to check the msb for negativity and then revert the 2's complement http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement, and by that you get the absolute value of the negative integer. in short, if msb is 1 -> write `-` and use the reverted 2's complement for itoa

Comment: I'm confused, the problem is just with your itoa function?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach Yes.  My apologies for posting the entire program.  Have since edited to only the itoa subroutine.

Comment: Could you perhaps comment on what the arguments and returns for this function are meant to be?

Comment: @KonradLindenbach Absolutely.  The argument is a0 (i.e. Fahrenheit value) and returns v0 after a1 is moved into v0.  For example, a0 = 18 (i.e. converted celsius value from a0) and will eventually have it's ASCII value stored in a1 and then moved into v0.

Comment: I've changed the name in your title from `Itoa` to `itoa`. Identifiers in many languages are case-sensitive, making `Itoa` and `itoa` distinct names; capitalizing them just creates confusion. (And in the font my browser uses, `Itoa` looks like `ltoa`.)

Comment: What is the version of instruction set you are using? You've forgot many mips feature aren't automatic... Were is delayed branch? out-of-oder execution? In which part Superscalar execution can happen?

Comment: @x4rf41 Your recipe gives a very nice infinite loop that prints many '-' in the case of 0x80000000

Comment: @user2284570 No idea.  All I know is I use MPLabX to compile my assembly code.

Comment: @MrPickle5 : The features are part of designs in the assembly language: You need to change your code to use them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include this in your code, right above `itoa_div_begin`:

```
li t0, 0x40000000
and t0, a0, t0
beqz t0, itoa_div_begin
nop
li t0, 45
sb t0, 0(a1)
addi a1, a1, 1
not a0, a0
addi a0, a0, 1

itoa_div_begin:
```

What is does:

- Check for a negative number by checking if the MSB is 1
- If so, insert `-` in result, and
- Use the two's complement of the number for the rest of the function